# split variables from texte

Tags: java, textarea, character

this method runs an exception and i didn't find why.

```
private void loadTrace () {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
  new StringReader(logTextArea.getText()));



String str;


try {


while(reader != null)

{

      str =reader.readLine();

String [] splitted = str.split("\\|");

String b = splitted[1].trim();
String c = splitted[2].trim();
String d = splitted[3].trim();
String Chemin;
String Type = "action" ;
String Description;
if (d!=null) {
    Description=d;
}
 else Description ="Afficher onglet";
if (c!= null) {
Chemin= b+"."+c;
    }
 else Chemin =b;
String trace =Type+" "+Description +" "+Chemin ;

ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();

p.add(trace);
System.out.println(p);


}


    }


      catch(IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: Your formatting is causing all sorts of code display issues. Please correct them.

Comment: you need to tell us what the exception is.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the exception I can guess one of the potential issue is in these lines:-

```
String [] splitted = str.split("\\|");

String b = splitted[1].trim();
String c = splitted[2].trim();
String d = splitted[3].trim();
```

You are accessing `splitted` without checking if it is null or size so you may run into ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception if `splitted` length is less than 3. So modify the code this way-

```
String [] splitted = str.split("\\|");
    if(splitted!=null && splitted.length==3){
      String b = splitted[0].trim();
      String c = splitted[1].trim();
      String d = splitted[2].trim();
    }
```

Comment: i tried your solution and it runs a new exception : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

The NullPointerException you get now that you've fixed the ArrayIndexOutOfBound is because of the test you use in your while loop:

```
while(reader != null)
{
  ...
}
```

reader will always be non-null so this loop will never end. You need to test if

```
reader.readLine()
```

returns null (indicating EOF).

Comment: it didn't run an exception but it just give the fist line with no stopping (loop never end)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you get an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException**, right? 
*(You need to tell us, what Exception you receive)*

The problem could be in the following lines. You should check the size of the array and not just "hope" that it has three parts.

```
String b = splitted[1].trim();
String c = splitted[2].trim();
String d = splitted[3].trim();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2